# Retrieving stdout from subprocess in Windows

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, pyqt, subprocess

I can call FFmpeg with subprocess.Popen and retrieve the data I need, as it occurs (to get progress), but only in console. I've looked around and seen that you can't get the data "live" [when running with pythonw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337870/python-subprocess-call-fails-when-using-pythonw-exe). Yet, waiting until the process finishes to retrieve the data is moot, since I'm trying to wrap a PyQT GUI around FFmpeg so I can have pretty progress bars and whatnot. So the question is, can you retrieve "live" data from a subprocess call when using pythonw?

I haven't tried simply compiling the application with py2exe yet as a windows application, would that fix the problem?

Comment: The question you've linked shows you how to use pipes with subprocesses -- have you tried that? What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(your_cmd, shell=true, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

count=0
while True:
    buff = process.stdout.readline()

    if buff == '':
        count += 1

    if buff == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break

    sys.stdout.write(buff)

process.wait()
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. I was actually using ALMOST the exact same code, however, I wasn't grabbing the stderr, thus it was giving me the Invalid Header issue. Upon adding the stderr in, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your call to subprocess.Popen, use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.  Then you will be able to read from the process's `.stdout`.