# pyinstaller on Windows with --noconsole simply won't work

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have a fairly simple GUI (wxPython) app and is working great. I'm using Windows 7.
When compiling it using `pyinstaller` with `-w` (or `--noconsole` or `--windowed`) and run it, I can see a console window for a millisecond and then it shutdown. The GUI app won't run.
Compiling without the -w will produce a working app with a console window.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using the -clean option. The console flashing for a second might show an error. Try running your built exe file from command prompt.

Comment: Already tried with the same result.

Comment: hmmm. you might want to try using py2exe and see if the results are same.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem. Used the following function instead of `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
def popen(cmd):
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, startupinfo=startupinfo, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    return process.stdout.read()
```

the return type is the same as you would get from `Popen().communicate()[0]` :)
Works great with my GUI application. Windowed with pyinstaller --noconsole...

Comment: Leon, your code helped me solve my problem. [My GUI Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61326495/8271606). Thank you greatly!

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that you are somehow launching a subprocess that gets messed up when Python runs without a console window. I have had to solve three problems related to this:

1. The `multiprocessing` module needs to [set an environment variable](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing) when it spawns worker processes.
2. The `subprocess` module needs to [explicitly handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/386343/4794) `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, because the standard file handles aren't set for subprocesses to inherit.
3. The subprocess creates a console window, unless you [tell it not to](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002-launching-a-subprocess-without-a-console-window/).

Comment: I found point 2 worked - explicitly handling stdin, stdout and stderr. We only handled stdout and stderr in our subprocess, but once we handled stdin it worked perfectly.

Comment: A few years later, I found this and #2 solved my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `subprocess.run()`, make sure it looks like:

```py
if os.name == 'nt':
    subprocess.run(command, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

be careful, `subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW` will throw an error on non-Windows.