# Selenium don't work after exporting to EXE in windowed mode in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyinstaller

I am making an PyQt4 application where I need to use selenium. Everything works fine while development but when I exported to *single file* EXE, by **pyinstaller** and *without console*, it produces following traceback error:

```
[WinError6] The handle is invalid
```

This doesn't happen when I export it when `console = True` (in pyinstaller spec file), The error is produced only *without console*.

The error produced is in the following line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
```

*My Specs:*

Python : **3.4**
Architecture : **64bit**
Selenium : **3.6.0**
Pyinstaller : **3.3**
OS : **Windows 10**

I googled about 1 hour but couldn't find any solution :(

Comment: You get any exception stack trace?

Comment: Yes this is traceback exception.

Comment: Update the stack trace in the question and not in comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found a solution for the above problem.

What you just need to do is edit the file:
`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`

Change the following line:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
```

to:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, creationflags=0x08000000)
```

This will work even while development and also after deploying to EXE.

Might be a selenium bug.

Comment: I found that keeping the close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows' parameter ensures that the IEDriverServer.exe process is always closed when your application is closed. This may preferred, since otherwise you end up with multiple invisible processes.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that pyinstaller doesn't create a copy of chromedriver.exe in the dist folder.
Copying chromedriver.exe file to there solved the problem for me.

Comment: For Firefox copy: geckodriver.exe

Comment: @Yehla, do you need to set a path to `chromedriver.exe` so it knows where to find it? Pasting it in the `dist` folder didn't make it work for me.

Comment: @tazboy I never used `chromedriver.exe`. With `geckodriver.exe` it worked without any modification. I just copied it into my Python project folder or in the same folder where the executable of my project was located.
I assume this should be the same for `chromedriver.exe`.