# Hide command prompt in Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Python? I've tried all the possible fixes posted here on StackoverFlow and outside, but nothing when I run my .exe, the cmd appears too.

Python 3.6, latest Selenium version (3.9).

Comment: instead of renaming the question as "SOLVED -", you must check mark the right answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide chromeDriver console in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

I found the way to replicate the above code in python (more or less)
Used this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520823/selenium-dont-work-after-exporting-to-exe-in-windowed-mode-in-pyinstaller)
as base to my inspiration.

After hours of struggling (and also really bad words), I've made this [**commit**](https://github.com/ITmasc/selenium/commit/05a5bb9e2dd603a0ee3ad05a94cc6063ff9c843b) on github bywhich console prompt behaviour is now easily changable via code.
I will try to make it available in the official sources. Hope it will make you save time and patience.

### STEP 1

Locate **service.py**, generally in *"X:\YourPythonFold\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py"*

### STEP 2

Replace these lines (n° 72-76 approximately, below start method def):

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                            close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                            stdout=self.log_file,
                                            stderr=self.log_file,
                                            stdin=PIPE)
```

with

```
if any("hide_console" in arg for arg in self.command_line_args()):
                self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)
            else:
                self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env, close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows', stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file, stdin=PIPE)
```

Finally in your code, when you setup your driver (I chose Chrome as example):

```
args = ["hide_console", ]
driver = webdriver.Chrome("your-path-to-chromedriver.exe", service_args=args, ...)
```

When edit the source code, be careful to PEP! Do **not** use tabs, just spaces!

Comment: I found that keeping the close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows' parameter ensures that the IEDriverServer.exe process is always closed when your application is closed. This may preferred, since otherwise you end up with multiple invisible processes.

Comment: tanks 
It was fully functional on pyqt

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been added in python library since **selenium4** release! See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python/71093078#71093078)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService # Similar thing for firefox also!
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW # This flag will only be available in windows

# Define your own service object with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW ` flag
# If chromedriver.exe is not in PATH, then use:
# ChromeService('/path/to/chromedriver')
chrome_service = ChromeService('chromedriver')
chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the most basic and simplest solution:

```
service = ChromeService('msedgedriver.exe')
service.creation_flags = 0x08000000
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a work-around for this problem: don't use the `-w` or `--Windowed` pyinstaller option. In other words, do this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile "main.py"
```

and not this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w "main.py"
```

Yes, you will get a command window at the beginning, but you don't get the window popping up every time the geckodriver.exe is called. I was struggling with firefox, hence geckodriver.exe