# How to execute geckodriver without displaying the cmd window?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am working with selenium webdriver in python.In my code I am controlling Firefox with the help of selenium and geckodriver.Everything goes well,except that when I convert it into an GUI executable and run it ,a geckodriver black screen appears.I have made the executable from python using this command:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile Main.py
```

So, initially I don't get a black screen.The black screen appears only when I am clicking a button associated with opening firefox using selenium webdriver.I understand that geckodriver is a dependency file for selenium,but isn`t there anything I can do or write in the python code that can prevent geckodriver from showing the black screen and still execute the command ?

Comment: Does the black screen appears when you run it without converting to exe?

Comment: @Nouman No,when I am running the python program in pycharm,it does not.

Comment: Try running it in python IDLE and let me know if it makes black screen pop-up.

Comment: @Nouman yes,it does,exactly the same way as when I run it s executable.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48802883/8321664

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide command prompt in Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654427/hide-command-prompt-in-selenium-chromedriver)