# Hide console by webdriver in windows PyQT5 application

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyqt5, pyinstaller

This question is absolutely the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python). But solutions there are not working for me :(

I'm using `undetected-chromedriver`, `webdriver-manager` and trying to put selenium scrapper behind the scene of `PyQT5` app which i build with `pyinstaller`

---

1. First i tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093078/15637940) by @Ali Sajjad. Trying set `self.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in `Service` object. I added prints to see changes.

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Scrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
        self.page_load_time_out = 20

    def get_driver(self):
        # options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        ...
        chrome_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        # try except block because import raising error not on windows machines
        print(chrome_service.creationflags)
        try:
            from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
            chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
        except ImportError:
            pass
        print(chrome_service.creationflags)
        driver = uc.Chrome(
            options=options,
            service=chrome_service
        )
        self.driver = driver
        print(self.driver.service.creationflags)

    def get_page(self, url):
        self.get_driver()
        print(self.driver.service.creationflags)
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(self.page_load_time_out)
        self.driver.get(url)
        ...
```

**1) Console output:**

```
0
134217728
0
0
```

2. Next step by me setting `self.driver.service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW`. Added `# difference`.

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Scrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
        self.page_load_time_out = 20

    def get_driver(self):
        # options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        ...
        chrome_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        # try except block because import raising error not on windows machines
        print(chrome_service.creationflags)
        try:
            from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
            chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
        except ImportError:
            pass
        print(chrome_service.creationflags)
        driver = uc.Chrome(
            options=options,
            service=chrome_service
        )
        self.driver = driver
        # difference !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        try:
            from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
            self.driver.service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
        except ImportError:
            pass
        print(self.driver.service.creationflags)

    def get_page(self, url):
        self.get_driver()
        print(self.driver.service.creationflags)
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(self.page_load_time_out)
        self.driver.get(url)
        ...
```

**2) Console output:**

```
0
134217728
134217728
134217728
```

So in my opinion it should works (cmd window of undetected-chromedriver should not open) now because value of `creationflags changed`, **BUT IT'S NOT WORKING...** still see this:
[image]

3. Then i tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39937466/15637940) from same question...Just did the same thing like in soulution in source code of `selenium.webdriver.common.service` and **It's working but only on mine machine**. If i share my app.exe, other people can't even run the script. They press button and app become frozen. **But** on my PC it's working, i don't see console by undetected-chromedriver.

---

Any help please. I'm building this app on virtual box's windows, it's painful enough if do this too long...

Comment: Why are you ignoring `ImportError` here? The `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag is definitely available in windows.

Comment: @AliSajjad I'm using linux on my pc and building this app on virtual machine. If i use this import on linux, i get `ImportError`. Anyway it doesn't matter because it is constant and i can see that i'm getting it with prints. Thanks for reply

Comment: It depends on the selenium version you are using. Try 4.5.0

Comment: Did you got to fix it?

Comment: @farhanjatt nope. May be Squalo provided solution, but i didn't try

Comment: The link below can help you completely, it worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48802883/8666584